# Referenced Java Project Compiled Update Doesn't Update Android Library Project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-library

I have an Android Project(A) that's my main application, it references an Android library Project(B).  The Library Project references a standard Java Project(C) which is my standard library for many Java and Android projects.  I will reference these three projects as A,B,and C.

My issue is if I make a change to the C project it will auto compile but B doesn't compile hence A doesn't see the changes.  The only way to do this is to clean B manually.  Is there a way in Eclipse to force B to re-compile when C is compiled?

Using Eclipse 3.6.2  with ADT 14 and SDK 14.

Comment: Are you, by any chance, running ADT 14 (the latest) or are you running an earlier ADT (12 or lower)?

It's just that Libraries are handled completely differently in ADT14 y'see

Comment: Yes ADT 14 I am running and how are libs handled compared to earlier?

Comment: Submitted a bug report for it http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21300&thanks=21300&ts=1319729709

Comment: You can test it out for yourself ad download the 3 projects from http://www.matthewscorp.com/download/test.zip

Comment: The difference between ADT12 and 14 (there was never a 13) is that 12 brings-in the source code for Android Libraries and compiles that wheras 14 compiles Android Libraries separately and brings them into your projects as JAR files.

My guess would be that because it's not seeing a change in the library project (B) it isn't re-making (B)'s jar.

The solution would be to 'Clean' your projects which will force them all to rebuild - note that you need them in alphabetical order (libraries first) or using the Settings/General/Build Order tab to tell it which libraries to compile first.

Comment: So far no update to the bug report I submitted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've also had this problem with ADT 14. In my case, I have less indirection (project A is the PLAIN java library (not an android library), project B is the android app).

What was really fun was that I had two project "B" (two android apps), and one was working. The other was an exact copy (with minor changes for a beta release), including a copy of the project files.

It compiled fine, but failed to package the library files on the beta version.

I removed the project (not deleting the files) and re-added it. Then, I also reconfigured the app's build path and removed the java library. Then I reconfigured it again and re-added it.

Clean/Build and it started packaging them correctly again.

I also did the build order trick mentioned earlier...it didn't help by itself, but may have contributed to the later eclipse refresh working (made sure library project built before others).

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue with ADT 20. Combing the comments with the accepted answer, I found that moving the library project to be the first in Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the accepted answer with project B (android) referencing project A (regular java). 
After removing and re-adding project B to the workspace, removing project A from project B's required projects, re-adding project B, ticking project B in project A's order/export and moving it to the top and finally clean/build all, my problem was not resolved. 
After the clean and build, all was up to date. But when IU changed anything in A, the changes were not visible in B.

My solution:

In the build path of the android project:
- select source tab
- click Link source
- select the java project's src folder. Name it linkedLibrarySource
- apply, clean build
- success

This solution is less than ideal, and I advice to try other solutions first.

There is a disadvantage: eclipse now adds a linkedLibrarySource folder to your android project. It contains the same files as the src folder of your lib. Eclipse sees them as different. This means that you can edit the same file on two locations, causing conflicts. So don't touch linkedLibrarySource!

I use ADT 20