# Android: Change in library project doesn't change App

Tags: android, eclipse, android-library

My Android app uses a library project which i've imported in Eclipse. So far everything works great. But now i try to change the library project (String.xml and the interface). I can see both changes in the graphical layout editor, but in the main app it doesn't changed.

I allready tried, restarts, cleans, remove and add again, nothing works, any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909175/referenced-java-project-compiled-update-doesnt-update-android-library-project/14184952#14184952